How to fix Xcode 16 Beta Predictive Code Completion Model download error?
Error:
Whenever I try to download the Predictive Code Completion Model in Xcode,
I'm getting this error:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (ModelCatalog.CatalogErrors.AssetErrors error 1.)
Domain: ModelCatalog.CatalogErrors.AssetErrors
Code: 1
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-08-23 08:55:17 +0000";
}
--
Failed to find asset: com.apple.fm.code.generate_safety_guardrail.tokenizer - no asset
Domain: ModelCatalog.CatalogErrors.AssetErrors
Code: 1
--


System Information

macOS Version 15.0 (Build 24A5327a)
Xcode 16.0 (23049) (Build 16A5230g)
Timestamp: 2024-08-23T16:55:17+08:00

System:
I'm currently using Xcode 16 Beta 6 and macOS 15 Beta 7. It was working before, but with the latest updates, it now appears to be broken.
Troubleshooting:
I already did a lot of restarts and reinstallation.
I also installed Xcode 16 Beta 5, and Xcode 16.1 Beta, but they now all have the same issue, so I'm guessing this is probably caused by macOS 15 Beta 7?
Status:
I can't find a lot of reports about this one. Even in the Apple Developer Forums, it only has this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/762638
I have already sent a report using the Feedback Assistant
Question:
Has anyone else in macOS 15 Beta 7 also encountered this one? and were you able to resolve this error?

UPDATE:
Problem is with macOS version and not with Xcode.
Latest macOS 15 Beta 8 still has the same issue.
However updating to macOS 15.1 Beta 3 allowed me to use Predictive Code Completion again. Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

Indeed, this seems tightly related to the macOS version, regardless of the version number. I had this error twice, and every time the fix consisted in simply updating macOS to the latest version. Upon updating and restarting, predictive code completion started downloading, installing and working again. I just did this again by updating to macOS Sequoia 15.1.1 from 15.1.

Sequoia 15.1.1, Xcode 16.1. I had Apple Intelligence toggled off in System Settings.  After turning it on the Predictive Code Completion Model installed without this error.

I faced the same issue recently. After trying various fixes, here’s what worked for me:
Solution: Free Up Disk Space
Ensure you have at least 18GB of free disk space.
Delete unnecessary files or move data to an external drive to increase available space.
Restart Xcode and attempt to download the Predictive Code Completion Model again.
This resolved the issue for me. It seems Xcode requires sufficient disk space to download and process the assets properly. If you’re still experiencing issues, try these additional steps:
Restart your Mac after freeing up space.
Clear Derived Data in Xcode (Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Derived Data > Delete).
Reinstall Xcode if the issue persists.
